# CSS overriding for 'font-weight' property

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm facing a strange problem with CSS overriding of 'font-weight' property. Given below is the code showing the issue:-

'font-weight' for element 'p' is set to small (in the same way color set to purple). But font is still rendering as bold on FF/Chrome, while color overrides to purple.

Any idea why this is happening?

```css
p {
  font-weight: small;
  color: purple;
}

#speciality_test {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.class_speciality_test {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="speciality_test">
    <p>
      Inside identifier... HTML CSS test pages.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="class_speciality_test">
    <p>
      Inside class... HTML CSS test pages.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no `font-weight:small;`. I think you mean `font-weight:normal;` or `font-size:small;`.

See also [CSS Fonts Module Level 3: 3.2 Font weight: the font-weight property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop).

Answer (score 3):

`font-weight` cannot be `small`. It's either `bold` or `normal`. So your declaration is just ignored.

See possible values here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

Answer (score 2):

Is `small` a valid value? According to W3C, it should be one of `normal`, `bold`, `bolder`, `lighter`, `inherit` or a number.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think small is valid.

```
font-weight: normal;
```

is what i use at work

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `small` is not a valid value for `font-weight`

```
font-weight: { 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900 | bold | bolder | lighter | normal | inherit } ;
```

So in your example, the font-weight from the `#speciality_test` is used.

[Sitepoint reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/font-weight)